# Target multiple <div> CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got this HTML structure and I want to target `divs` in CSS like this :

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE --> 
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
```

I don't know how to target these `divs` in CSS, using `nth-child` ?

**Edit: No using classes**

Comment: Please show us what CSS you have tried so we can highlight where you are going wrong.

Comment: Adding a class is always an option.

Comment: If it sohuld be generic some `:nth-of-type()` will be ok

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
div:nth-child(4),
div:nth-child(5),
div:nth-child(6),
div:nth-child(11),
div:nth-child(12),
div:nth-child(13) {
    /*your style*/
}
```

**Note:** This solution, of course, is only useful if you can't add classes to the specific divs in question. Also, it would apply to any sequence of divs in your site. So, you should probably point a div id for a parent before the div part, if you choose to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

This is running code try this

```css
div:nth-child(4){
color:red;
}
div:nth-child(5){
color:blue;
}
div:nth-child(6){
color:white;
}
div:nth-child(11){
color:orange;
}
div:nth-child(12){
color:pink;
}
div:nth-child(13){
color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>no style</div>
<div>no style</div>
<div>no style</div> 
<div>red</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>blue</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>white</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>no style</div>
<div>no style</div> 
<div>no style</div> 
<div>no style</div>
<div>orange</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE --> 
<div>pink</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>yellow</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the div you need to style. The sample is given below:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE --> 
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="specific_style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->

and in CSS update by using the class like .specific_style { //styles }

Hope This is helpful
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #babafe;
}

.your-style {
  background-color: #bafeba;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div>
<div></div> 
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE --> 
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div class="your-style"></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
```